# Unexpected output by synchronized block in java

Tags: synchronization

This is the simple program of java which illustrate synchronize block.
Look at this program carefully.

```
class Table{
public void printTbl(int n){
    //synchronize block
    synchronized(this){
        for(int i=1; i<11; i++){
            System.out.print(" "+i*n);
            try{
                Thread.sleep(600);
            }catch(Exception e){}
        }
    }//synchornize block end
    for(int j=0; j<5; j++){
        System.out.print(" "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
        try{
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }catch(Exception e){}
    }
}
}
class Table1 extends Thread{
Table t;
public Table1(Table t){
    this.t=t;
}
public void run(){
    t.printTbl(2);
}
}
class Table2 extends Thread{
Table t;
public Table2(Table t){
    this.t=t;
}
public void run(){
    t.printTbl(5);
}
}
public class Sync2{
public static void main(String... args){
    Table tb=new Table();
    Table1 table1=new Table1(tb);
    Table2 table2=new Table2(tb);
    table1.start();
    table2.start();
}
```

}

After i compile and execute this program, i got following result.

> 2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20 5 Thread-0 10 Thread-0 15 20 Thread-0 25 30 Thread-0 35 Thread-0 40 45 50 Thread-1 Thread-1 Thread-1 Thread-1 Thread-1

In this result feel something awkward. This is because, i have make block in printTbl() method synchornize. After i call **table1.start();** the output was expected that is **2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20**. But after first block releases lock next for loop was executed. But in the mean time second thread that is **table2.start()** got the cycle and it should execute the synchronize block first and only the next for loop, but here, thread are running alternatively. Why is this so? Can anyone give me answer.